# Converting a C# List DateTime Column to String type without breaking sort order

Tags: c#, silverlight, list

I have a C# List with one particular column as of DateTime.

I have to bind this column to CategoryAxis of Silverlight Chart -  hence looking for converting this DateTime column to String type with formatting as .ToString("dd-MMM-yy") without altering any sort order.

Any inputs?

Comment: A List only has one column.  Do you mean a List of objects?  What are you binding it to?  You could do the conversion in the UI where the bind is declared.  It would be helpful if you would post sample code and markup.

Comment: The WCF-Reference Completed event gives me List result in all string objects. 

I converted one column in it to DateTime using:
var orderResult = e.Result.OrderBy(O => Convert.ToDateTime(O.RowPeriodEndDate)).ToList();

I now want to change it back to string as my sorting is already done.

Comment: isn't the orderResult what you want? it does not change any thing but the order only, isn't it? the conversion of the string O.RowPeriodEndDate only occurs once during sorting but it does not change the value at all .

Comment: @Rex, you mean to say orderResult  already contains RowPeriodEndDate as of type string?

Comment: if the original type is string, then it should not change - calling OrderBy(O=>Convert.ToDateTime(O.RowPeriodEndDate)) won't change your object signature

Answer (score 0):

Add one more field in list and store the string date in it using for each loop.

Comment: Say you have a `List<DateTime>` - how is the OP going to make that a `List<DateTime, String>`?

Answer (score 0):

add one more read-only wrapper property to it, something like:

```
public string StrDT
{
    Get
    {
       return myDateTime.ToString("dd-MMM-yy");
    }
}
```

then bind this field to wherever you like...

Comment: I wont be able to change the structure of this List by adding deleting any property into it. This is from WCF.